# React Routes not working after building the app using webpack

Tags: .htaccess, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

React Routes not working after building the app using webpack

The routes are working fine when I am running the app using the webpack server (npm start)

**webpack.config file**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'index': [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './index.jsx'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8881/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.es6'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.jsx$|\.es6$|\.js$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.scss$|\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!style!css!sass'}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/'
        }
    },
    externals: {
        'Config': JSON.stringify({
            serverUrl: "http://pss/",
            authSuccessUrl: "http://localhost:8881/loginSuccess",
            podioClientId: "property-seller-solutions"
        })
    }
};
```

**package.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "pss",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --hot --port 8080"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "~6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "~6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "~6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "~6.5.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-html-replace": "^1.6.1",
    "gulp-react": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "history": "~3.0.0",
    "react": "~15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "~15.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "~1.3.0",
    "webpack": "~1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.1.6",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "~1.2.0",
    "halogen": "^0.2.0",
    "highcharts": "^4.2.5",
    "react-d3-basic": "^1.6.11",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^1.4.1",
    "react-infinite-scroll-es2015": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**.htaccess File:**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

After building the app (webpack --hot --inline), got two output files - index.js and index.html

I copied the two files and the .htaccess file to my localhost root folder.

The index route is working fine..(http://localhost), but when I am trying to redirect to http://localhost/home its showing "404 Not Found" Error (The requested URL /home was not found on this server.)

These routes are working fine when I am running the app using the webpack server (npm start) - http://localhost:8080/home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked.

Used the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

And used the following terminal command to build the project using webpack:

```
webpack --inline --history-api-fallback --progress -p
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your app to serve index.html when visiting /home.

Answer (score -2):

To my understanding,if you say http://localhost:8080/home it will made server-side router call. You need it setup it first,

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md

Comment: Link is dead. May I suggest for the next answer to put the quote from the link you attach in case of the situation we have here?